# Wrong: export to excel with php and mysql

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to export data from `Mysql` and `php` to an excel file.

but something is wrong.

this is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) 
{
  header('Location: login.php');  
}

require('../conexion.php');
  $conexion = conexion();

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("La conexión con el servidor de base de datos falló: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $consulta =  $_SESSION['query'];
    echo $consulta; //consulta = SELECT * FROM cotion where status= 'Vea' 
    $resultado = mysql_query ($consulta, $conexion) or die (mysql_error ());
 $registros = mysql_num_rows ($resultado);

 if ($registros > 0) {
   require_once 'excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

   //Informacion del excel
   $objPHPExcel->
    getProperties()
        ->setCreator("Creator")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("setLastModifiedBy")
        ->setTitle("tittle")
        ->setSubject("Subject")
        ->setDescription("Description")
        ->setKeywords("Keywords")
        ->setCategory("Category");    

   $i = 1;    
   while ($registro = mysql_fetch_object ($resultado)) {

      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $registro->pais);

      $i++;

   }
}
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="ex.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter=PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
mysql_close ();
?>
```

But i only can see it:

[image]

but I do not see it in the excel file, I see it in the web browser.

I looked [here](http://ingenieroweb.com.co/exportar-datos-desde-mysql-excel-con-php) to do my exports, and download the `PHPExcel` class from [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

**Any idea about what could Ido?**

Thank you

Comment: You are setting a header at the top that says the file type is `text/html`. Try removing that.

Comment: I removed the `header` but, Still seeing the same ��s

Comment: I just deleted the `echo ` as @Mark Baker said.. But the problem continues

Answer (score 1):

Note the `caution` in the PHPExcel developer docs section on [Redirecting output to a client’s web browser](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#redirect-output-to-a-clients-web-browser):

> **Caution:**
>
> - Make sure not to include any echo statements or output any other contents than the Excel file. There should be no whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag and at most one line break after the closing `?>` tag (which can also be omitted to avoid problems).
> - Make sure that your script is saved without a BOM (Byte-order mark). (Because this counts as echoing output)
> - Same things apply to all included files

Note also that if you're using some kind of framework, it may be sending different headers, or generating additional outputs. Most frameworks provide some mechanism to allow you to override that behaviour.